# Invalid character test

Tags: c, encoding, character-encoding

when i execute that with 'é' it is accepted although the test! help!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char  ch[10];
    int i,k,k1;

do
{
    k=0; i=0;   
    printf("Write a sentence without accentuated letters:\n");
    scanf("%s",ch);
    k1=strlen(ch);
    while ((k==0)&&(i<k1))
    {
        if (ch[i]=='é') k=1;
        i++;
    }
}   
while (k==1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's generally best to post your code in English here.

Comment: ok,printf("Donner une chaine de caracteres vide de caractères accentuées:\n"); ---means---printf("write a sentence without accentuated letters:\n");

Comment: sorry for the french sentence !

Comment: Please give more info : what OS are you using, and what encoding is your source ? your terminal ? if your source is encoded in latin1 and your input is encoded in utf8, it won't work. Equally if your source is encoded in latin1 and your terminal is encoded in cp850 (like it usually is on windows)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably with encoding. `é` can have different numerical representation depending on the encoding standard used. If your source code editor, compiler and your command line use different encodings, things will never work this way. You might want to switch to UTF-8.